# Google adsense ad is overlapping my drop down menu

Tags: z-index, adsense

In my website the Google adsense ad is overlapping my drop down menu even I tried to fix it by using z-index property. I applied `ul z-index:99999` and Google adsense ad `div -99999 z-index`. But it doesn't make any difference. What will be the working solution? Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav_bar"> <!-- NAV BAR STARTS -->

    <ul id="nav"> <!-- NAV STARTS -->
        <li><a class="active" href="providers">Providers</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="actrix.html">Actrix</a></li>
            <li><a href="digital-island.html">Digital Island</a></li>
            <li><a href="farmside.html">Farmside</a></li>
            <li><a href="flip.html">Flip</a></li>
            <li><a href="inspire.html">Inspire</a></li>
            <li><a href="maxnet.html">Maxnet</a></li>
            <li><a href="orcon.html">Orcon</a></li>
            <li><a href="slingshot.html">Slingshot</a></li>
            <li><a href="telecom.html">Telecom</a></li>
            <li><a href="telstraclear.html">TelstraClear</a></li>
            <li><a href="vodafone.html">Vodafone</a></li>
            <li><a href="woosh.html">Woosh</a></li>
            <li><a href="xnet.html">Xnet</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="compare">Compare</a></li>
        <li><a href="reviews">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul> <!-- NAV ENDS -->

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>

<div id="google_ad_banner">
<!--<img src="images/banner-ad.png" class="responsive" />-->
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle responsive-ad-unit-1"
    style="display:block"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
    data-ad-slot="xxxxx"
    data-ad-format="horizontal">
</ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav_bar ul li ul {
    display: none;
    z-index: 99999;
}

#google_ad_banner {
    z-index: -99999;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide more information(Link, HTML, CSS, Jquery, Jsfiddle and etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using only id of top hierarchy and set position to relative

```
#nav_bar {
position: relative;
z-index : 999999;
}
```

Comment: Wow! that really worked. So it means I was missing out `position`. Thanks.